# Why Application Variable data lost after some time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have situation where i have to store data in application variable when i am storing data from global.asax file data persist.
if i am writing same code for store data in application variable from any aspx page data lost after some time i am wondering why it is happening please suggest below is my code ?

```
//storing data in application variable from aspx page
protected void getApplicatinVariable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
HttpContext.Current.Application[paramTypeId] = GetSelectedParameter(paramTypeId, flag);//fuction retruning string data
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationApplication["GroupUserListCache"] = CacheClass.GetGroupUserListCache();//get userlist
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationApplication["EquipListCache"] = CacheClass.GetAlarmEquipListCache();
}   

//from global.asax file in dis case data persist.
Application[paramTypeId] = CacheClass.GetSelectedParameter(paramTypeId, "");
Application["GroupUserListCache"] = CacheClass.GetGroupUserListCache();//get userlist
Application["EquipListCache"] = CacheClass.GetAlarmEquipListCache();//CacheClass.SetEquipment();
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate(v=vs.110).aspx) on `HttpApplicationState` which is the base object for `HttpContext.Current.Application`:

> An ASP.NET application is the sum of all files, pages, handlers, modules, and code within the scope of a virtual directory and its subdirectories on a single Web server.
>
> A single instance of an HttpApplicationState class is created the first time a client requests any URL resource from within a particular ASP.NET application virtual directory. A separate single instance is created for each ASP.NET application on a Web server. A reference to each instance is then exposed via the intrinsic Application object.
>
> Application state is not shared across either a Web farm (in which an application is hosted across multiple servers) or a Web garden (in which an application is hosted across multiple processes on the same computer).

So technically if you are in a shared environment it would not persist but for a single application it only starts an instance of that class when the first request happens.

Comment: can you link the source of your quote?

Comment: added the link for you

Comment: agreed but i have hosted this application on my local machine and only one application hosted there.So there is no chance for web farm or web garden and i am testing it in my local area network. still after some time it lost.

Comment: One thing you can maybe check, not saying that, that is the case but IIS performs recycling every now and then dependent on your set frequency if the instance is idle. Could it be perhaps that you application gets recycled in that time, is there other variables you can monitor like cached objects perhaps to check if recycling is indeed happening?